# GRASS r.horizon returns nonsense

Tags: grass-gis, dem, elevation

I am trying to calculate the horizon profile from a point on a mountainside, through the appropriate DTM elevation file and the GRASS function `r.horizon.height` (via QGIS).

However, the output looks like this:

[image: horizon profile]

I know for a fact that it is wrong and that the flat portion should contain positive angles too. Compare with the output of HeyWhatsThat.com using Google Earth data:

[image: another horizon profile]

For starters, barring the staircases coming from interference of terrain close by, the huge mountain face in the S direction should be there (in red), which it is not!

[image: error highlight]

As a **sanity check**, I ran `r.viewshed` to examine visible terrain from the point.

To my surprise, the viewshed appears to be *correct*, the mountain is there:

[image: viewshed]

Therefore, it looks like that there is no issue at all with the elevation model. `r.viewshed` correctly shows that portions of the terrain are visible, while those portions are non-existent in the `r.horizon` output.

It just seems so weird that the output of `r.viewshed` would be correct and inconsistent with the one of `r.horizon`. I tried several observation points and `r.horizon` usually gets the output wrong to some extent.

What is going on here with `r.horizon`? The documentation for the script sheds no light on this issue.

Comment: The terrain model, for the record: https://www.geoportale.piemonte.it/geonetwork/srv/api/records/r_piemon:224de2ac-023e-441c-9ae0-ea493b217a8e

Comment: The same glitch appears when doing the math with a different DTM10 model of the same area. So maybe I got something about `r.horizon` wrong?

Comment: Since it seems as if portions of terrain far away do not get taken into account, I thought that it could be a problem with the maximum distance parameter. However I tried many different values for it to no avail, the result is always the same.

Comment: I responded on grass gitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

r.horizon has been [fixed](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/3441), it will be part of upcoming GRASS 8.3.2 release.